# typedef not recognizable in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to convert a cpp file to a .cu file . However the compiler is reporting errors for all the typedefs and static functions in cpp. It also does not detect the scope resolution operators and report errors for them as well.

Comment: Obviously CUDA is working for a lot of other people, so could you be a bit more specific and show some (self-contained) code that does not work?

Comment: I already have an existing project . We plan to migrate one cpp file to a cu file . While compiling this cu file we get the errors . For eg.  typedef unsigned long ULONG;   If i use in a function declaration Func(ULONG uLine);  I get an error "identifier ULONG is undefined"

Comment: Well, this is not happening for a lot of other people, so there must be something specific to your program that causes this behavior and we would need to see the code to identify this. My general advice would however be not to try converting large existing codes to .cu files, but to wrap your kernel launches and CUDA calls into small functions that you call from the existing .cpp files.

Comment: I'll turn that advice into an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA makes some significant changes to the way preprocessor macros are expanded, as it runs the code through the preprocessor multiple times to expand the CUDA constructs and separate host and device code. This is likely to break large existing code bases.

My general strategy in this case (and even with newly written projects) has been to keep all the existing code in .cpp files and only move as little code into .cu files as possible. I just move the typedefs and defines that are needed in .cu files as well as .cpp files into separate headers, and write small wrapper functions around CUDA calls and kernel launches which I then call from the existing .cpp files.

Comment: agreed ... but I have not any yet implemented any CUDA API calls . I have just added  a cu file to my existing project . And my first step is to compile the cu file

Comment: @sameer karjatkar a simple compilable example of the problem you are seeing, along with the definition of how you are compiling it, would help, as already stated. For example, in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168624/cuda-unspecified-launch-failure-error), code is provided in a pastebin right at the beginning of the question.  That code compiles just fine, and uses a __typedef unsigned int uint;__ right at the top and __uint__ throughout the code, without any compiling issues.   A statement like "compiler is reporting errors for all the typedefs" isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Ok ..as suggested by @tera I have created a seperate header file named .cuh . I have added this file to my project . I include this cuh file in my cpp file . Now I build the module ....now the compiler is unable to identify the  
__global__ keyword . The function is 
__global__ void kernel(int *a, int *b)
{
   int tx = threadIdx.x;

   switch( tx )
   {
case 0:
    *a = *a + 10;
    break;
}
}

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using v4.2. I have just included my cuh file in my cpp file using #include

Comment: a .cu file, or any file that contains device code, must be passed through the nvcc compiler, and this is normally done through a .cu file (or with a .cuh included into a .cu file).  My guess is you are passing that .cpp file to some other compiler.  That won't work.  Once you changed your .cpp file to a .cu file and started adding cuda constructs to it (like __ global__) you need to compile it with nvcc, not gcc (linux) or cl (windows).  .cuh files, if they contain device code,  are not intended to be included in .cpp files.

Comment: change your .cpp file back to a .cu file extension, if you are passing it to nvcc

Comment: My custom build rules are set to CUDA even for cpp files . So CUDA compiler is getting called for the cpp file as well . so if I rename my cuh file to .cu  and then try to call a function from a cpp file ... will it be OK ?

Comment: Any device code must end up in a .cu file and be passed to nvcc.  You can call C/C++ functions in your .cu files from cpp files.  You may want to review the [cpp integration sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cpp-integration).  Sounds like you are using windows.  You should start by verifying that you can compile and build the sample projects (like cpp integration).  If you have changed the cuda build rules beyond that, I think it's asking for trouble.

Comment: Thx for the Link of sample examples